# UIScrollView does not maintain its scroll position

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a long screen which is filled with `UITextField` and picker controls. When I scroll down to a specific field and clicks onto the `UITextField` control to input data, the UIScrollView automatically gets scrolled up to the start of the screen.

Please suggest how can I control the scroll position.

**Main UIView: x:0, y:0, width:320, Height:1000**

Ios 8.1 & xcode version -> 6.1.1

Thanks!

Comment: What's written in UITextFieldDelegate methods? Provide some code to help.

Comment: How You Add UITextField in UISCrollView post Some Code for help.

Comment: UITextFiled is added by dragging and dropping within UIScrollView area on the storyboard. Initially i selected all the controls within UIScrollVBiew and embedded those into a UIView. But for some reason, I deleted the container view.  @Mrunal: Within UITextFieldDelegate, only first responder is being resigned.

Comment: Because there must be some code, which changes the frame of scrollview while textfield editing started (when keyboard shows up). Is there any such method?

Comment: This line of code is written in viewDidload method: [self.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 82, 0)];self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints= NO;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;

Comment: Same issue is happening when I click UISwitch control.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you all to use below codeless library for keyboard handling.

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

pod 'IQKeyboardManager'

You don't even need to write any code, just drag and drop and it will work.